# Get user input from EditText, query that word from SQLite database and populate result

Tags: android, sqlite

I am learning programming and trying developing very basic Dictionary Application using Android Studio.

Database and table created, when application runs and able to populate data  using following query. 
`Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE WORD = 'home' ", null);`

The problems is that, 
in **MainActivity** class, I have created a method

```
public EditText getEditText(){
    EditText getText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_SearchWords);
    return getText;
}
```

and in **DatabaseHelper** Class.

```
public Cursor getWord() {
    MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
    EditText searchWord = obj.getEditText();
    String word = searchWord.getText().toString();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE WORD ="+word, null);
    return res;
}
```

However, after implementing above query and method, App crashes and does not do anything. It have been playing up for a week and couldn't figure out the problems. Any help would be great support in my learning.

Comment: What would be the alternatives then ?

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace with your answer.?

Answer (score 0):

You cant just create a new main activity object and pull the view from it.
If you're calling getWord() from inside the Activity then try passing in the text as a parameter instead since you will have access to the EditText there.

And even if you do call the method from the activity and fix that, you shouldn't access the db from your live thread.

Look into using a CursorLoader:
http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html

Or calling an AsycTask that runs the query and returns the response:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: you really shouldn't do it... I don't know why you would need to... I would suggest reading up on what activities are, how they work and some basics of object oriented programming... If you can give me a bigger picture of what you're trying to do I may be able to help you with the design...